# Unknown symbol flush_cache_range in linux device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am just writing my very first linux device driver, and I have ran into a problem. I want to prevent one memory region from being cached, so I have been trying to use `flush_cache_range()` and `flush_tlb_range()` to flush the cache for this memory region. Everything compiles well, but when I try to load the kernel module I get the following errors:

```
Unknown symbol flush_cache_range (err 0)
Unknown symbol flush_tlb_range (err 0)
```

I find this very strange. Shouldn't they be defined in kernel?

I know that alternatively  I could also use `dma_alloc_coherent()` to allocate a non-cached memory region. But I don't have a device structure and passing NULL for this parameter didn't cause any errors, but I also couldn't see any of the data that was supposed to be there.

Some information about my system: I'm trying to get this running on a ARM microcontroller with an integrated FPGA (the Xilinx Zynq). The FPGA copies some data to a memory location specified by the CPU. Now I want to access this memory without getting old data from the caches.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use functions such as `flush_cache_range()` because they are not intended to be used by modules.

To allocate memory that can be accessed by a DMA device, you *must* use `dma_alloc_coherent()`.
This requires a valid device structure so that it can do proper mapping between memory addresses and bus addresses.

If your device is not on a bus that is handled by an existing framework (such as PCI), you have to create a platform device.

Comment: Thanks, I think I finally got it running, even without a device structure. It does seem to work when passing in a NULL pointer for the device. My problem was actually somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

1- flush_cache_range doesn't "prevent one memory region from being cached" .. It just simply flush (clean + invalidate) the caches. Any future writes/reads to this memory region through the same virtual range will go through the cache again.

2- If the FPGA is writing to memory and then the CPU are going to read from this memory, probably flushing the cache isn't the correct thing to do any way. Usually what you need to do is to invalidate the memory region and then tell the FPGA to write.

3- Please take a look at "${kernel-src}/Documentation/DMA-API.txt" in the kernel sources. It has plenty of information about how you can safely ( cache maintenance + phys_to_dma translation ) use a specific region of memory for DMA.